# SQL - Select SUM with other mathematics operations

Tags: sql, sum

In a select statement, I have mathematic operations associated with  SUM().
For example,

```
select SUM(A * (B) / C) - (D + E + F) 
from   MyTable
where  cond1 = cond1
and    cond2 = cond2;
```

By running this under SQLDev, it asks me a *GROUP BY* option, which should not be needed.
By adding it, another error message appears.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: And what DBMS are you using? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ... SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS, because answers may differ.

Answer (score 0):

You have columns A, B and C in SUM() function. But D, E and F not in SUM(). You should GROUP BY columns, which are not in SUM, i.e tables D, E, F

Comment: A,B,C,D,E are column from MyTable.

Comment: If I use  select sum(50 * (2) / 100) - (6+1+3) from dual; It works fine but not with the original select statement.

Comment: This is because you can have more than 1 row in original table. And you should group them.

Comment: You don't need SUM for that case @laurent . `select (50 * (2) / 100) - (6+1+3) from dual;` will give you the same result. So that is a different case. You should have aggregation on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression contains an aggregation `SUM(A * (B) / C)` over all rows which results in a single result row (for the lack of a `GROUP BY` clause).

It also contains `(D + E + F)` which seem to be values found in single rows.

The DBMS complains that it doesn't know which row to take the values D, E, and F from.

Maybe you want to sum the complete expression `SUM((A * (B) / C) - (D + E + F) )`?

Comment: Hello. Thx. I have tried several bracket possibilities but with no result

Answer (score 0):

There are different options on what you might want.  Here are three possibilities:

```
select SUM(A * (B) / C) - (D + E + F) 
from   MyTable
where  cond1 = cond1 and cond2 = cond2
group by (D + E + F);
```

Or:

```
select SUM(A * (B) / C) - SUM(D + E + F) 
from   MyTable
where  cond1 = cond1 and cond2 = cond2;
```

Or:

```
select SUM(A * (B) / C) - (max(D) + max(E) + max(F)) 
from   MyTable
where  cond1 = cond1 and cond2 = cond2;
```

You haven't provided sample data and desired results, so it is hard to say which if these (or variations on them) might be what you really want.